# Measure results disappear when row level security is applied in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, row-level-security

I inherited a report that calculates commission totals for sales reps.  After updating the calculations within the measures to this year’s goals we went to test the row level security to find the results of the measures don’t appear for the sales group.  The management group can see everything just fine.   The security works fine with each rep only able to see their name, but the results from the measures are not visible in the matrix that’s bult for them.   Also, other measures on the matrix work just fine.  Just the ones updates were made to are not working.

Any suggestions on what could cause this and how to troubleshoot?

We’ve double checked the security, and nothing is showing to be filtered that shouldn’t be.
Tried building the same visual on a different page.
Tried to rebuild the measures again from scratch (the measures work just fine, until we test the row level security for this group)